# SMTPException : Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed

Tags: c#, email

I know that this question looks like duplicate of dozens other questions while its not.

When ever i try to send an email on my local machine through my web application an SMTPException is thrown and the exceptions is :

```
//on this line : SmtpServer.Send(mail);
Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.
```

While the code on production is working perfectly, the same code, the same connections, the same credentials, i'm using IP instead of alias, i tried to turn off the firewall on my local machine, and nothing helped me to fix this issue.

While on my local machine is used to work previously, can anyone give just a hint what could be the problem that raising this issue?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are on a residential internet connection, quite often your ISP will block outgoing email sends by blocking all outbound connections to port 25.  This is quite common here in the US.  Try connecting to a local email server over TCP/IP, or to one on your own internal network.

Comment: That is correct, My ISP was blocking the connection, i dont know why they did it recently, but as i said it was working previously, Thank you,

Comment: Quite a few do that to attempt to limit the effect of malware on people's machines from sending out spam using their network.

Comment: I've AT&T Uverse and interestingly port 587 targetting gmail's smtp server succeeds but 465 fails with message given in question above.

Answer (score 7):

[This thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/924682.aspx) contains some.

For instance: it looks like [assigning a static IP](http://forums.asp.net/post/1198752.aspx) might solve the problem.

> What this error means is that System.net.mail was unable to find the
>   smtp server.
>
> The answer will vary depending on whether you have a fixed IP or a
>   dynamic IP but,  basically, you need to assign a valid IP to your smtp
>   server.
>
> With fixed IP's this is relatively straightforward. With dynamic IP's
>   it takes a bit of tweaking.
>
> Open the IIS Manager and check the properties for the smtp server.
>
> In the Default SMTP Virtual Server's properties, in the "Access" tab,
>   in the Connection Control and Relay dialogs, make sure that your local
>   IP is assigned. ( In my case, it's 10.0.0.2... )
>
> You may also need to modify your hosts file, to point 127.0.0.1 to
>   your machine name. ( \WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts )
>
> Then, in your code, assign your machine name to the smtp client :
>
> ```
> Dim client As New SmtpClient("yourmachinename") client.Send(mail)
> ```

Alternatively another guy in the same thread [seems to have found a workaround](http://forums.asp.net/post/2873125.aspx) for the SMTP connection not being correctly closed.

> Set `SmtpClient.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 1` according to a supported
>   work-around:
>   http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/Workaround.aspx?FeedbackID=146711
>   which makes all smtp work properly.
>
> Here's a complete sample:
>
> ```
> MailMessage msgMail = new MailMessage();
> msgMail.To.Add(new MailAddress("info@somedomain.se"));
> msgMail.Subject = "Message from web";
> msgMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
> msgMail.Body = "Test message";
> SmtpClient Client = new SmtpClient();  /* uses settings form web.config */
> Client.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 1; /* without this the connection is idle too long and not terminated, times out at the server and gives sequencing errors */
> Client.Send(msgMail);
> msgMail.Dispose();
> ```

Comment: If you set `Client.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime`, set it to 2 instead of 1 to avoid CPU issues discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1190727/945875

Answer (score 0):

System.Net.NetworkCredential(user, password); ///Wrong 
System.Net.NetworkCredential(email, password); ///right

because some email server is shability

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to leave out the `Domain` property from `Network Credentials` when setting username and password

Answer (score -3):

The Gmail account you are using has limit for number of emails being sent out per day/month and if you exceed that limit, it will reject any further outgoing emails.

Comment: "When ever i try to send an email" does not sound as if the OP is mass mailing...